# Como exibir dados de uma tabela da chave estrangeira na minha tabela principal?

Tags: php, mysql

No PHP como eu faço para aparecer ao invés do id da chave estrangeira, apareça o campo que possui os dados?

Minha tabela de grupo tem a coluna `id_grupo` e coluna `grupo_nome`.

Eu tenho tabela de produtos ai tem os grupos do produtos que cadastrei em outra tabela, mas quando eu coloco para exibir no php, ao invés do nome está aparecendo o numero do grupo.

esse é código que aprendi para chamar os dados da tabela

tabela produto

```
   prod_id|prod_nome     |prod_grupo
   1      |Rebite Pop 406|    1
   2      |Rebite pop 406|    2
```

Tabela grupo

```
grupo_id |   grupo nome
1        |    alumínio
2        |    inox
```

Esse código na minha página php

```
<?php
include("conexao.php");
$consulta = "SELECT * FROM cadastro_produtos";
$con = $conn->query($consulta) or die($conn->error);
?>

<?php while($dado = $con->fetch_array()){ ?>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $dado["prod_id"];?></td>
<td><?php echo $dado["prod_nome"];?></td>
<td><?php echo $dado["prod_grupo"];?></td>
</tr><?php } ?>

<td><?php echo $dado["prod_grupo"];?></td> aparece o numero, como faço para aparecer o nome do grupo ?
```

Obrigado

Comment: Por favor amigo poste o código que você está usando.

Comment: Pesquise sobre `JOIN` e `RENAME`, são conceitos de banco de dados.

Comment: Obrigado, vou pesquisar, valeu

Comment: WHERE  grupo_nome = '$grupo_nome'; se conseguir avisa...se naum num durmo...sério

Comment: vou testar aqui

Comment: posta o script dos tabelas

Comment: Andei lendo e comando where é ruim para tabelas com vários produtos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bom, a **informação** que você quer exibir **está numa outra tabela**, não é mesmo?

Você quer exibir o campo `grupo_nome` que está na tabela `grupo`.

Na sua tabela de `produtos` você tem uma relação com o grupo, através do campo `prod_grupo`, que é uma **chave estrangeira (*FK - Foreign Key*)**.

O que você precisa fazer é uma ligação entre as duas tabelas na sua consulta e então pode recuperar a informação que quer. Fazemos isso através de operações de ***JOIN***. Assim:

```
SELECT p.*, g.grupo_nome
  FROM cadastro_produtos p
 INNER JOIN grupo g ON p.prod_grupo = g.id_grupo
```

Daí na página basta usar:

```
<td><?php echo $dado["grupo_nome"];?></td>
```

Note que no ***JOIN*** usamos as chaves estrangeira e primária pra fazer a ligação entre as tabelas.

Mais informações sobre ***JOIN***: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html

Comment: Deu certo, valeu mesmo, vou estudar mais
substitui meu $consulta = "SELECT * FROM cadastro_produtos";
por $consulta = "SELECT p.*, g.grupo_nome
  FROM cadastro_produtos p
 INNER JOIN grupo g ON p.prod_grupo = g.id_grupo". Deu tudo certo, muito obrigado

Comment: Que bom que deu certo amigo!